# Retrieve tree recursive data from foreign key

Tags: php, python, mysql, sql, json

I've some table and it's data in MySQL, but I need to retrieve all the data in tree display based on it's foreign key.

> Table Structures

**Table Post**

```
+=====================================================================+
| column | type | nullable | key    | foreign_key | rel_tbl | rel_col |
|========|======|==========|========|=============|=========|=========+
|Id      |INT   | NO       |PRIMARY |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Posts   |string| NO       | NO     |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|PostMed |INT   | yes      |INDEX   |yes          | PostMed | Id      |
|User    |INT   | NO       |INDEX   |yes          | User    | Id      |
+=====================================================================+
```

**Table User**

```
+======================================================================+
| column  | type | nullable | key    | foreign_key | rel_tbl | rel_col |
|=========|======|==========|========|=============|=========|=========+
|Id       |INT   | NO       |PRIMARY |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Name     |string| NO       | NO     |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Email    |string| NO       |unique  |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|UserPhoto|string| NO       |unique  |Yes          |UserPhoto|Id       |
+======================================================================+
```

**Table UserPhoto**

```
+======================================================================+
| column | type | nullable | key    | foreign_key | rel_tbl | rel_col |
|========|======|==========|========|=============|=========|=========+
|Id      |INT   | NO       |PRIMARY |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Value   |string| NO       | NO     |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Type    |string| NO       | NO     |NO           | NO      | NO      |
+=====================================================================+
```

**Table PostMed**

```
+======================================================================+
| column | type | nullable | key    | foreign_key | rel_tbl | rel_col |
|========|======|==========|========|=============|=========|=========+
|Id      |INT   | NO       |PRIMARY |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Value   |string| NO       | NO     |NO           | NO      | NO      |
|Type    |string| NO       | NO     |NO           | NO      | NO      |
+=====================================================================+
```

> And This is the data

**Post**

```
+=============================+
|Id | Posts  | PostMed | User | 
|===|========|=========|======|
|1  |Hello   | 1       | 1    |
|2  |World   | Null    | 1    |
|3  |Dominate| 2       | 2    |
+=============================+
```

**Users**

```
+====================================+
|Id | Name  | Email        |UserPhoto|
|===|=======|==============|=========|
|1  |kzul   | kzvl@mail.com|1        |
|2  |jhon   | jhon@mail.com|2        |
+====================================+
```

**UserPhoto**

```
+===========================+
|Id | Value     | Type      |
|===|===========|===========|
|1  |kzul.jpg   | image/jpeg|
|2  |jhon.png   | image/png |
+===========================+
```

**PostMed**

```
+===========================+
|Id | Value     | Type      |
|===|===========|===========|
|1  |kzul.jpg   | image/jpeg|
|2  |jhon.mp3   | audio/mp3 |
+===========================+
```

As you can see, the table posts had 2 foreign key column ***PostMed*** and ***User***, ***Postmed*** column had relation with table **PostMed** referenced by Column ***Id***, also ***User*** column had relation with table **User** referenced by column ***Id***.
so the tasks is when I try to retrieve all data from table **Posts** it must in be JSON type and formatted in tree like this:

```
[
  {
      "Id": 1,
      "Posts": "Hello", 
      "PostMed": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": "kzul.jpg",
            "Type": "image/jpeg"
      }, 
      "User": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "kzul",
            "Email": "kzvl@mail.com",
            "UserPhoto":{
                 "Id": 1,
                 "Value": "kzul.jpg",
                 "Type": "image/jpeg",
            }
      } 
  },
  {
      "Id": 2,
      "Posts": "World", 
      "PostMed": null, 
      "User": {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "kzul",
            "Email": "kzvl@mail.com"
            "UserPhoto":{
                 "Id": 1,
                 "Value": "kzul.jpg",
                 "Type": "image/jpeg",
            }
      } 
  },
  {
      "Id": 3,
      "Posts": "Dominate", 
      "PostMed": {
            "Id": 2,
            "Value": "jhon.mp3",
            "Type": "audio/mp3"
      }, 
      "User": {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "jhon",
            "Email": "jhon@mail.com"
            "UserPhoto":{
                 "Id": 2,
                 "Value": "jhon.png",
                 "Type": "image/png",
            }
      } 
  }
]
```

If I retrieve other table which have foreign key, it will look like above.
any example in PHP or Python, suggest tools or algorithm I can use to create my data like those tree?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: any ORM/Active Record library like Doctrine or Eloquent with proper relation definitions will do this for you "out of the box".